# Qt - Setting Focus on a floating QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, focus, floating, qdockwidget

my basic process is that I create a floating dock widget and then try to give it focus. I've found that so long as it is docked in the main window then it works as expected however as soon as i call  it  will no longer be called correctly.

Im using Qt 5.14 and C++.

Heres the relevent code for my methods.

```cpp
DockPanel::DockPanel(QWidget *parent, QWidget * hold_widget, QString title, bool popup) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    popup(popup)
{
    setObjectName(title);
    setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable);
    DockPanelTitle * panel_title = new DockPanelTitle(this, title);

    setTitleBarWidget(panel_title);
    setWidget(hold_widget);

    if (popup)
    {
        setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
        setFloating(true);
        setFocus();
    }
}
```

```
void WindowToolBarButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    QMainWindow * cw = window()->findChild<QMainWindow *>("CentralWindow");
    HolderWidget * widget_a = new HolderWidget(this);
    QPoint m = window()->mapToGlobal(cw->pos());    

    DockPanel * panel_a = new DockPanel(cw, widget_a, btn_label->text(), true);
    panel_a->setGeometry(m.x(), m.y(), 300, cw->height());

    cw->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, panel_a);

    cw->setFocus();
    QWidget * w = qApp->focusWidget();
    for (DockPanel * child : w->findChildren<DockPanel *>())
    {   
        child->setFocus();
        QString s = child->objectName();
        std::cout << "Widget: " + s.toStdString() + " has focus " << child->hasFocus() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Edit - Sorry Im missing the last two brackets from the mousepressevent, it doesnt seem to want to format.

So to summarise im trying to figure out why a floating QDockWidget cant be given focus but a docked one can and if there is a possible solution.

[image: Result]